# java server read data from HttpInputMessage is very slow

Tags: java, http, inputstream

Our game on android sends a login request to server. When the server gets the request and read data from the `InputStream`, it is very slow.

```
public static byte[] streamToByte(InputStream input) throws IOException {
    ByteArraryOutputStream baos = new ByteArraryOutputStream();
    int len = 0;
    byte[] b = new byte[4096];
    while((len = input.read(b, 0, b.lenght)) != -1) {
        baos.write(b, 0, len);
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a `ByteBuffer`?

Comment: i cant understand why inputstram read slow when it read the end.

Comment: InputStream.read() will block until it can read data or the stream ends. Perhaps not all data Is in the buffer when you read it.

Comment: It can't read any faster than the sender is sending. There is nothing wrong with this code, except that there really isn't any need to create the byte array. You should just return the input stream and let the caller deal with it. This way you're just adding latency and wasting time and space.

Comment: hi，EJP。I also think server are wait data from client. But game client only send a http request with a json data which is 400 bytes. And game client send request through android HttpURLConnection. So why the client send http request so slow ?